# How to read multiple cell values from Datatable in same sentence?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable with 5 columns Refer [DataTable.txt](https://pastebin.com/yjF0rRS9)

```
results = dt.Select("select = 'yes'");  
Console.WriteLine("Companies we hired from :" + results[0]["Organization"] + "," + results[1]["Organization"]);
```

Expected output: People hired in 1-5 years experience range: 3
People hired in 5-10 years experience range: 1
People hired in 10-15 years experience range: 0
Companies we hired from: Cognizant, Planit

```
Console.WriteLine("Companies we hired from :" + results[0]["Organization"] + "," + results[1]["Organization"]);
```

is able to give me expected output but instead of using row index as in results[0]["Organization"]
Is there another way so that if the query returns n values the it can be displayed in same sentence as in expected results??

Comment: var results = dt.AsEnumerable(),Where(x => x.Field<string>("select") == "yes").Select(x => new { id = x.Field<string>("id"), name = x.Field<string>("name")}).ToList();

Comment: Thanks @jdweng it worked . I just made few changes though

Answer (score 0):

```
var results1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("select") == "yes")
              .Select(x => x.Field<string>("Organization")).ToList();  
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Companies we hired from: " + string.Join(", ", results1)));
```